# Package for Summarizing Data in My DataFrame R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a huge dataset containing information about 1774 counties in the US. The variables there are things like income quartile, voter preferences, median household income etc.

I would like to know if there exists a package which would allow me to quickly see for example the number of counties which have income over a certain number and voted Republican, or the number of counties where more than 50 % work in services, while the average education attainment is HS or lower.

I know that I can do so with dplyr functions, however, that is extremely time-consuming when I want to do it with large amounts of variables.

Thank you for any recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try the [explore package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/explore/index.html).

While you can use it manually to explore specific parts of your dataset, it has additional features to explore data interactively via shiny (`explore_shiny`) and to generate a report of your entire dataset via rmarkdown (`report`).

Exploring pairs of variables (e.g. income by party voted for) is possible by specifying one variable as the `target` and selecting the second variable. But it won't always give you the comparison you need. Hence I would recommend the explore package as an initial starting point for understanding your data, but for specific analysis you will probably need to write your own dplyr, ggplot, and/or plotly code (or whichever other packages you favour).

Further worked examples are found in its [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/explore/vignettes/explore.html).